# PhantomJs: fs:Module: stream object writeLine Method is not working

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to use the stream object from the fs module. But it does not seem to work. below is my cofee script to reproduce the issue. Could someone please check the script and tell if this is a bug or I am doing it wrong. Thanks in advance. I also posted this question in PhantomJs group, but have not got any answer.

```
fs = require 'fs'
data = 'test fs'
fs.write 'tex.txt',data,'w'

rfile = fs.open('rfile.txt','w')
rfile.writeLine('testLine')
rfile.flush
rfile.close
phantom.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake.
In coffee script, when calling the functions, that does not have any arguments should include parenthesis in the call. The below coffee script works.

```
fs = require 'fs'
data = 'test fs'
fs.write 'tex.txt',data,'w'

rfile = fs.open 'rfile.txt','w'
rfile.writeLine 'testLine'
rfile.flush()
rfile.close()
phantom.exit()
```